# implicit operator on types like DateTime without datetime-functions like ToShortDateString()

Tags: c#, .net, generics, properties, implicit-conversion

I want to use the generic class with implicit operators. The problem is to use underlaying functions. I think the best describtion is my code

```
public class AnnotationField<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsNullValue { get; set; }
    public CompareTypes CompareType { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(AnnotationField<T> temp)
    {
        return temp.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator AnnotationField<T>(T temp)
    {
        Type correctType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
        AnnotationField<T> annotationField = new AnnotationField<T> {};
        annotationField.Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(temp, correctType);
        return annotationField;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
public AnnotationField<DateTime> Birthday { get; set; }

myObject.Birthday = new DateTime(1986, 7, 2); // <- Works
myObject.Birthday.ToShortDateString();  // <- Compiler-Error !
myObject.Birthday.Value.ToShortDateString();  // <- Works
```

If the DateTime is nullable I need another method-calling

```
public AnnotationField<DateTime?> Birthday { get; set; }

myObject.Birthday.Value.Value.ToShortDateString(); // <- Works but is not really usable!
```

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want to, at least not without using reflection and losing type safety. For T that you can inherit from, it's doable, obviously. Doesn't help you with structs though.

Comment: Or, if you don't care about type safety and the intellisense goodness, you could use a dynamic type.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) on `AnnotationField<DateTime?>` type:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static string ToShortDateString(this AnnotationField<DateTime?> item)
    {
        return item.Value.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

With that, you'll be able to call:

```
public AnnotationField<DateTime?> Birthday { get; set; }

myObject.Birthday.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: I think the idea is the OP doesn't want to have to add these types of methods manually, he wants to implicitly inherit them.

Comment: sorry but I don't want to add all methods as extensions. This is not my idea behind the generic class

Comment: So I have to say, you're not using Generics right. Generics make sense, when all types have something in common (e.g. implement the same interface). Otherwise your functionality is not generic at all.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that's a pretty constrained view on the use of Generics, the point is to allow type-safety regardless of the implementation. Personally I don't see anything wrong with this approach, it's effectively a container which provides some context of a particular data type.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no way of doing this. Problem being the compiler see's the `ToShortDateString` method being called on `AnnotationField<DateTime>` not `DateTime` as the implicit stuff only happens at runtime, not compile time.

If `struct` supported inheritance you could have just derived from `DateTime`, however, as it stands the only way you could accomplish this would be to either derive from `AnnotationField<DateTime>` and introduce those methods and delegate the calls or a more abstract approach would be to use an extension method (as already suggested).